# Does cubic spline interpolation preserve both monotony and convexity?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, interpolation, spline, monotone-functions

I have a question. Let's say i have a function $f(\cdot)$ such that $Dom(f) = [a,b]$. The function is at least of class $C^2$ and it is both strictly monotone and convex.

My question is, does a spline interpolation preserve such properties? if yes how to prove it? otherwise how to disprove? any condition for which the preservation holds?

Comment: No. Have you heard of Lagrange splines? Then, you know why. They wiggle...

Comment: Lagrange spline == lagrange interpolant polynomial?

Comment: No. But they are defined similar. A spline that is 0 at every knots except one, at which it is 1. It oscillates less than the Lagrange polynomial, but it oscillates

Comment: Constrainded spline could be a solution to preserve properties instead? (i heard of $L$-splines somewhere)

Comment: Yepp. There bunch concepts, like shape preserving splines or m splines (for monotone). There is also quasi interpolation

Comment: Is there a theorem or an example that proves the oscillation property you mentioned? (with specific reference to spline).

Comment: hmm. Just make a minimal example

Comment: Like which one?

Comment: Like the one I told you? On each side of the knot with function value $1$ the data are monotone (however not convex)

Comment: Please... (i know it could bother you) can you give the answer with the example? (i can build the spline itself by myself). Anyway your example sounds "monotone" not "strictly monotone" to me.

Comment: Interpolate to the data $x=(0,1,2,3,4)$ and $y=(0,0,1,0,0)$ and you will see. The interpolating spline is continuous in the knots and data. So you can alter the data slightly to make them strictly monotone and keep the oscillation

Comment: Ok, but you're starting from a set of sample points. I don't know if it does matter or not... but how can i be sure that the samples are taken from a function such that meet the properties i described? Because that's the point of my question.

Comment: You asked whether cubic spline interpolation preserves monotonicity and convex. The answer is in general no. If you are interested in some particular cases, then please post them as part of the question.

Comment: I said class $C^2$ at least, so namely a function where the derivative up to the second one exists in $[a,b]$, where the function is $f'(x), f''(x) > 0 \;\;\; \forall x \in [a,b]$. In general i can assume $f \in C^{\infty}[a,b]$, if that could help of course.

Comment: The won't affect my example you know ...

Comment: Even if i assume $C^{\infty}$?

Comment: It doesn't matter as **interpolation** only relies on finitely many points

Comment: Yes but error properties rely on the functions properties (like this [paper, theorem 5](http://www.math.fsu.edu/~gallivan/courses/FCM2/HallMeyerJAppThe76.pdf), so this is why my question arises, with such hypothesis on the original sampled function.